# Error with HTTPClient after upgrading to Angular 6 the api call redirected to localhost:4200

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I got a problem after upgrading to Angular 6 from Angular 5.
I'm using 2 interceptors one from "@auth0/angular-jwt" to inject the Authorization header and i'm using another one i created to change any url with #myAPI# to a specific url

here the code

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (req.url.startsWith('#myAPI#')) {

      req = req.clone({
        url: req.url.replace('#myAPI#', 'http://localhost:0987/api' ),
      });
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

and JwtModule configurations in AppModule

```
export function jwtOptionsFactory(cookieService) {
  return {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return cookieService.get('AuthToken');
    }
  };
}

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
        deps: [CookieService]
      }
    }),
]
providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
]
```

Now the problem is if i'll do request using HTTPClient like this

```
this.http.get<any[]>(`#myAPI#/Users`)
```

magically the request will be turned to call http://localhost:4200/ and get the page html data and try to parse it as json which is not expected.

```
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/",
  "error": {
    "error": {},
    "text": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n  <title></title>\n\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n </head>\n<body>\n  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>\n\n     </div>\n\n\n\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"runtime.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"polyfills.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"styles.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"scripts.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"vendor.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"main.js\"></script></body></html>"
  }
}
```

i expect to get array of any.
i tried to debug the interceptor it self but it's not reaching the intercept function it self.
But, i'm using TranslateModule for example to get the translation and it works fine and i have another request 
like `this.http.get<any>(`#myAPI#/Blogs/1`)`
and it's not about if it's array or object because i tried to use just get or get and get and it didn't work.
any idea how i can debug or know why sometimes it's not going to the interceptor and some times it do.

Comment: can you console log the interceptor before the `if` block to see if it even works?

Comment: @MikeTung i tried to print something at the begging of the intercept method before doing anything and as i mentioned it's not reaching it in most of the cases at all :(

Comment: stackblitz this so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: What is the name of the interceptor which is responsible for changing URL? Have you provided interceptor in Angular providers array. How many module do you have in your Angular Application?

Comment: @MikeTung  i tried to reproduce it on stackblitz but i'm not able to get the same error :(

Comment: @RitwickDey it's called AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor, it's about 12 module

Comment: Just give a try. (I'm not sure.)  Angular 6.0 introduced a new `root` application injection. Just decorate your `AuthInterceptor ` with  `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work, i think it's the same as registering the service as provider in appModule, the thing is it's registered but it goes for the interceptor for one time and in other time go somewhere change the url to be localhost:4200/